# Customize StackPanel To Alternate Colors With Child Controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a StackPanel that I dynamically hide/show items from, and I would like to make it so that the background property of each item alternates (white and grey). I tried doing it programmatically, but it is quite inefficient as the code that sets the background of each item  runs every time an item is hidden/shown. I know that maybe using Styles/Templates could solve this, but for some reason this particular feature of WPF has confused me every time I try to learn it. Could someone please show me how to do this?

Also, I have thought of using ListBox/ListViews rather than StackPanel, but trust me that due to my particular implementation they don't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with any ItemsControl using triggers on attached property ItemsControl.AlternationIndex (sample - http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-set-wpf-listview-alternate-row.html) but i don't think it is possible in xaml only with StackPanel. Are you sure doing it programatticaly is slow? I am quite sure it will work fast enough so you don't need to bother.

Comment: I was going to recommend that same thing but Nikolay beat me to it.

Comment: It was slow just because the action happened so often on a list that was potentially thousands of items large. Thanks for the answer.